# Eloquent. Fetching multiple relations and ordering them

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a user model which belongs to many 'event' and also belongs to many 'me_resource'.

For an activity log I want to get all of the users events and me resources then order them by the pivots updated_at attributes.

Something like this is what I am looking for

```
user->events()->me_resources()->orderBy('pivot.updated_at')->get()
```

But of course me_resource is a relation on user not on events and also they are each related to user via a different pivot table.

Here is an example of what the query should return

```
id:87, resource_name:'hello', ..., updated_at:21/12/2015 //newest
id:32, event_name:'meeting', ..., updated_at: 20/11/2015 // second newest
id:11, resource_name:'questions', ..., updated_at: 27/02/2015 // third newest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep using Eloquent relations, I'd suggest using `Collection`s to handle the logic for you.  Using the query builder probably would be more efficient though.

```
$user = User::with('events', 'me_resources')->find($user_id);

$collection = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();
$collection->merge($user->events);
$collection->merge($user->me_resources);
$results = $collection->sortByDesc('updated_at');
```